# algorithm that removes extraneous connections from a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

For a nondirection graph $G=(V,E)$, I need to write an algorithm that finds connections that can be removed without destroying the graph (ex: a connection from a child of a child back to the root of the graph). I have created an algorithm with a runtime of $O(|V|+|E|)$ (utilizing BFS):

```
    smallerGraph(G,s):
    for all vertex u from V[G]do
      color[u]=WHITE
      p[u]=NIL
      n[u]=NIL
    end for
    for all vertex u from V[G]do
      if color[u]==WHITE then
        modifiedDFSVisit(G,u)
       end if
    end for
    return 0
    modifiedDFSVisit(G,u):
    color[u]GRAY
    for all vertex v from Adj[u]do
      if color==BLACK and p[v]!=u and p[n[v]]!=v then
        removeLink(u,v)
      end if
      if color[v]==WHITE then
        p[v]=u
        n[u]=v
        modifiedDFSVisit(G,v)
      end if
    end for
    color[u]=BLACK
```

Additionally, I am also looking algorithm that can solve the same problem, however this time with a runtime of $O(|V|)$. If this is possible, if someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. If it isn't possible, why? Would the answer change if I was given a list of the connections (as well as the number of connections)?

Comment: Do you want to find *all* edges that can be removed?  If so, I don't think that can be done in $O(|V|)$ time; solving this problem seems to require reading all vertices and edges, and it takes $\Theta(|V|+|E|)$ time even to read the input, let alone do any interesting computation on it, so it seems that any solution to this problem will need at least $\Omega(|V|+|E|)$ time.

Comment: What does "destroy" mean? Keeping the graph connected? In that case, *spanning trees* are what you're looking for.

Comment: Finding an arbitrary cycle in $O(|V|)$ seems quite doable.

Comment: @D.W. What if I was given a list of all the connections (I would also know the number of connections)?

Comment: I assume by "connection" you mean the same thing as "edge".  I was already assuming you are given a list of all edges (connections).  That's what it means for an algorithm to be given a graph $G$ as input: part of the specification of the graph is a list of all edges (at least, when the graph is specified in adjacency list representation, which is the standard assumption if no other information is provided).  So that doesn't change my answer.

Comment: Are you talking about the [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) of a graph?

Comment: @PålGD some seems to think bout spanning trees, knowing the difference would probably change the algorithm that handle this. Because in a case of a tree you can't have what you have in the wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

You describe the graph as

- $V$ - a set of vertices
- $E$ - a set of edges, where each edge is (presumably) an unordered pair.

To determine where you can go from each vertex $v \in V$, you need to scan the whole of $E$, so you are already $\Theta (|V| + |E|)$.

If the graph is in the form ...
$$ V \rightarrow 2^V$$
... then you can find a spanning tree in $\Theta(|V|)$. To *enumerate* the edges left out, you are up to $\Theta (|V| + |E|)$ again. But if you don't need to enumerate them, you can determine whether any given edge is spare in constant time.

---

**Correction**

> If the graph is in the form $ V \rightarrow 2^V$, then you can find a
>   spanning tree in $\Theta(|V|)$.

I think this is wrong. Whatever your search order, at each vertex you have to look through the neighbours to find an undiscovered one, which might be the last. Depending on the structure of the graph, this might happen at every vertex. So the worst case at least is $\Theta (|V| + |E|)$.